# Whats the correct way to build a grails plugin for deployment

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I created a Grails 3.1.1 plugin, and run the "gradlew jar" command. It produced a .jar file of size 53KB. When i run the "gradlew build" command, the jar file is now 44MB. Looking at the contents of the file, the 2nd file had many of the jar files that a application would have (such as grails-plugin-async-3.1.1.jar).

So, is the "gradlew jar" command the recommend way to build a jar file for Grails plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/package-plugin.html) the correct way to package a plugin for use with a Grails project is: `grails package-plugin` which:

> Packages a plugin as a JAR archive which can then be installed into
>   another application